# how to add an attribute to a class

Tags: python, list

Just a quick question. I've been researching online and I can't seem to find the answer.

How do you append an element to an object list?

```
from tkinter import *
class Movie:

    def __init__(self, movie, ratings):

        self.movie = movie
        self.ratings = ratings
        
class MovieRaterGUI:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.counter = 0
        self.index = 0
        
        #variable set up
        self.v = StringVar()
        self.v.set(" ")

        #frames used so you can easily switch between rating frame and summary frame - keeping the search frame
        rating_frame = Frame(root)
        search_frame = Frame(root)

        rating_frame.pack(side="top", expand=True)
        search_frame.pack(side="bottom", expand=True)

        #rating frame

        #list of ratings for movies
        self.movies = [
        Movie("The Hobbit", ["No Rating", "Forget it", "2", "3", "4", "Must See"]),
        Movie("Coraline", ["No Rating", "Forget it", "2", "3", "4", "Must See"]),
        Movie("Love, Rosie", ["No Rating", "Forget it", "2", "3", "4", "Must See"])]

        
        #labels
        self.movie_label = Label(rating_frame, text = "Please Rate:", borderwidth = 10)
        self.current_movie = Label(rating_frame, text = self.movies[self.counter].movie, borderwidth = 10)
        self.rating_label = Label(rating_frame, text = "Your rating:", borderwidth = 10)

        self.movie_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.current_movie.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.rating_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.num_choices = (self.movies[self.index].ratings)
        
        for i in range(len(self.num_choices)):
            self.option = Radiobutton(rating_frame, variable = self.v, value = i, text = self.num_choices[i], borderwidth = 10)
            self.option.grid(row = i+1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        next_btn = Button(rating_frame, text = "Next", borderwidth = 10, command = self.next_movie)
        previous_btn = Button(rating_frame, text = "Previous", borderwidth = 10, command = self.previous_movie)

        next_btn.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W)
        previous_btn.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W)

        #search frame
        
        self.search_label = Label(search_frame, text = "Search for movies with a rating of:", borderwidth = 10)
        self.search_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=len(self.num_choices))
        
        for i in range(len(self.num_choices)):
            option = Radiobutton(search_frame, variable = self.v, value = i, text = self.num_choices[i])
            option.grid(row = 1, column = i, sticky = W)

        show_btn = Button(search_frame, text = "Show", borderwidth = 10)
        show_btn.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = len(self.num_choices))

    def next_movie(self):
        self.movies.append(self.option)
        self.counter +=1
        self.current_movie.configure(text = self.movies[self.counter].movie)
        

    def previous_movie(self):
        self.movies.remove(self.option)
        self.counter -=1
        self.current_movie.configure(text = self.movies[self.counter].movie)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Movie Ratings")
    radiobuttons = MovieRaterGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to add the radio button that the user clicks on to the Movie Object lists for each list in the self.movies list. I am trying to do this when the user clicks the next or previous button.

Thank you!

Comment: How is `Movie` defined?

Comment: Can you please give some more details about the `Movie` object?

Comment: You can use `*args` in your constructor though. `def __init__(self, moviename, yourlistarg, *args)`. In this way you can pass more arguments in Movie.

Comment: reading the "create a new class" part of any python programming tutorial or books  can be helpful.

Comment: I have added my whole program: @DavidS

Comment: It looks like you're doing it right. I see you doing `self.movies.append(...)`. Why do you think that's not working?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

Ex: `setattr(object, 'field', value)`

Answer (score -1):

You can append the list by .append()

For example

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.append(6)
print(a)
```

Result:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Now to insert in different positions

In python first position is [0]

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.insert(1,6)
print(a)
```

Result:

```
[1,6,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Hello! How would you do it if it was an object, not a list

Comment: To be able to append to an object, that object will need to implement an 'append' method. List object have an append() method but there is no reason to expect some random object that you are using to have an append method. You can find all the methods an object has via the command 'dir(name_of_object)'